# Hibernate: HQL is not working

Tags: java, sql, hibernate

I wrote a **SQL** query in my hibernate application using **where** clause and **and** .

Here is method ,

```
public List<Comobility> getComobilityByIdComobilityItemsAndIdPatient(int idComobilityItems, int idPatient, Session session) {
    Query query = session.createQuery("from Comobility where comobility_items_idcomobility_items= :idComobilityItems and patient_idpatient= :idpatinet");
    query.setParameter("idComobilityItems", idComobilityItems);
    query.setParameter("idpatinet", idPatient);
    List<Comobility> list = query.list();
    return list;
}
```

But this is not working . There is no any exception or error . Actually, there is no any result.

Have any ideas ?

Comment: what error/exception are you getting

Comment: *"But this is not working"* How so? In what way is it not working? What behavior are you seeing? Is it a compile error? Is an exception thrown at runtime? Are you getting back unexpected results from the database?! What's wrong?

Comment: @mhasan :No any exception or no any errors . That's why I am confused .

Comment: @nbrooks : Look at above comment.

Comment: @Barrier No exceptions or errors? Sounds like everything is working then, awesome!

Comment: @nbrooks : May be . Have you got any idea ?

Comment: @Barrier By "no results" do you mean the list your code produces is empty? And you've verified that data exists in the database, matching your search criteria?

Comment: @nbrooks: Not all issues generate errors, you have 13K+ points, you should seriously know that even though you are a student.

Comment: @nbrooks :Yes , but I have some data in my database table . Also I used those data .

Comment: @PeakGen All issues have symptoms. In the general sense "error" doesn't only mean the compiler/JVM complained, it means something isn't working. If everything was working fine, then the OP wouldn't have posted a question. But prior to the edit, there was no description of any actual symptom of an error. No need to be condescending either, I haven't been a student for a while. `:)`

Comment: @nbrooks: Right. But the request made is for exception or errors, which means asking JVM logs, that's why I said not in all cases you can get error. Anyway the priority of this post shouldn't be this discussion, therefor I am gonna leave this thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try like that

1. Wrap your method with try catch block. I believe the query has an error then it will enter to catch block

   ```
   public List<Comobility>getComobilityByIdComobilityItemsAndIdPatient(int idComobilityItems, int idPatient, Session session) {
       try {
            logger.debug("xxxx")
            //do comething
       } catch (Exception e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
       }
   }
   ```
2. Make sure your method parameters are not `null`
3. Check your list is empty or not.
4. For checking you can use IDE debugger or put some logs in your method.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check the generated SQL in the log and execute it against database. If query is compiled and no records are returned, means there are no records for the particular criteria.

To generate the SQL by Hibernate, please set property `show_sql` to `true` in hibernate configuration.